# Convert from class to functional code in React Native

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native

How do I transfer the follwing code from CLASS to FUNCTIONAL component? This Backhandler part looks like it belongs to React Native so I would have thought that this could be converted to Functional code instead of being within a Class. If there's some other ways that you know of to achieve the same thing handling the back button, please let me know.

Current versions:

```
"react": "16.13.1",
"react-native": "0.63.4",
"react-navigation": "^4.4.4",
"react-navigation-stack": "^2.10.4"
```

Code:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import {... BackHandler... } from "react-native";
import { withNavigation } from "react-navigation";


class DetailScreen extends Component {

    componentDidMount() {
        BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this.handleBackButton.bind(this));
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        BackHandler.removeEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this.handleBackButton.bind(this));
    }

    handleBackButton = () => {
        this.props.navigation.pop();
        return true;
    };
}


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
 .......
})


DetailScreen.navigationOptions = () => {
    return {
        header: () => null,
        ...TransitionPresets.SlideFromRightIOS,
    }
}

export default withNavigation(DetailScreen);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add this in your functional component to achieve the same result, the first part allows it to subscribe to the button press on mount, and the return statement happens on unmount to remove the subscription

```
useEffect(() => {
        const backHandler = BackHandler.addEventListener(
            "hardwareBackPress",
            () => {
                handleBackButton();
            }
        );
        return () => backHandler.remove(); //this might require edits based on your RN version
    }, []);
```

the syntax used could be different based on your RN version, but basically you subscribe inside this useEffect and unsubscribe in the return

Comment: Thanks, i'll give it a try. What would go in the handleBackButton() in this case? Remember, the class related code would disappear.

Comment: that's up to you, I guess you want props.navigation.pop(); same as your old code, don't forget to mark it as solved if it helped you ^^